# prob of obtaining the second "female" card before third "male" card?

Tags: probability

suppose that we draw cards repeatedly and with replacement from a file of 200 cards,100 of which are refer to male n other 100 are refer to female persons. what is the prob of obtaining the second "female" card before third "male" card?

Comment: Which book is this from?

http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/suppose-draw-cards-repeatedly-replacement-file-200-cards-100-refer-male-100-female-persons-q1609875

Answer (score 1):

So we "win" if $2$ females occur before the third male. We could enumerate cases, but here is another way.

We modify the game slightly, by drawing $4$ cards whatever happens. Then we will have at least $2$ females or at least $3$ males, and we cannot have both. Also, we win the first game precisely if in the modified game we have $2$ or more females. By standard techniques, the probability of this is 
$$\binom{4}{2}\frac{1}{2^4}+\binom{4}{3}\frac{1}{2^4}+\binom{4}{4}\frac{1}{2^4}.$$